# How can I resize the window after a widget is hidden while still allowing the window to be resized?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

Here is a simple example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Show/Hide')
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame.setFixedHeight(100)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.frame.setLayout(layout2)

        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout2.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Yoyoyo'))

        self.button.toggled.connect(self.clickAction)

    def startup(self):
        self.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def clickAction(self):
        checked = self.button.isChecked()
        if checked:
            self.frame.show()
        else:
            self.frame.hide()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = MainWindow()
    myApp.startup()
```

When the button is toggled, the frame is shown/hidden appropriately. I realize if I set the `MainWindow`s `sizeConstraint` to `SetFixedSize` as follows:

```
layout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
```

that the window will resize like I want. However, I wish for the user to still be able to resize the window, which `SetFixedSize` will not allow me to do.

Therefore, how can I achieve both a user-resizeable window while still having it resize based on it's contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the conversation found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/4500/resize-top-level-window-to-fit-contents/2) I was able to get this to work. The solution involved adding a `QTimer` after showing/hiding the frame. The `QTimer` calls a `resizeMe` method, which is also defined below.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Show/Hide')
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.frame.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.layout = layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.frame.setLayout(layout2)

        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.frame)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout2.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Yoyoyo'))

        self.button.toggled.connect(self.clickAction)

    def startup(self):
        self.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def clickAction(self):
        checked = self.button.isChecked()
        if checked:
            self.frame.show()
        else:
            self.frame.hide()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resizeMe)

    def resizeMe(self):
        self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp = MainWindow()
    myApp.startup()
```